# Awkward search controller animation on unwind to view with hidden navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

So I'm following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial on UISearchController, and modified it slightly. I created a `RedViewController` before the `SearchViewController`, in which the navigation bar is hidden. As you can see in the animation, unwinding from the `SearchViewController` to the `RedViewController` isn't kind to the search bar. Additionally, if you don't complete the unwind segue (by swiping back, then forward), the entire search bar disappears. I tried dismissing the search controller on `viewWillDisappear`, but it didn't work.

[Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFu0P.gif)

SearchViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationItem.searchController?.dismiss(animated: false)
}
```

RedViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Try to put search controller setup  code in view will appear instead of  viewDidLoad

Comment: Still does it, unfortunately